# How do I find the strings menu in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, string

This might be really silly but I cannot find the menu where I can see all my strings in Android Studio like I could in Eclipse. If you could tell me where this is I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: do you refer to strings.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a strings.xml file in a directory something similar to app/src/main/res/values/